# Ubuntu 14.04: The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I know there are other posts about this. I have tried EVERYTHING I can find and I continue to have this obnoxious issue on my production servers. I used this guide (RVM version, Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 3.2.22):

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

It was a fantastic guide and got me all setup. I needed to get into the database to make a change that wasn't possible to do through the site's GUI and quickly found that, apparently, Rails isn't installed on my server.

...despite the site serving up just fine.

So I Googled the issue. I tried adding lots of stuff to my ~/.bashrc file. Nothing works. NOTHING. WORKS.

No matter what I do, this is what I get when I try to open the Rails console on my production servers:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:

* ruby-railties-3.2
* ruby-railties-4.0

Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package="">
```

So after looking at a number of posts and articles, I've tried the following:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Does nothing.

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Just in the terminal and in ~/.bashrc does nothing.

```
/bin/bash --login
```

Does nothing.

It's the same message every single time I try to run the console and I'm at a complete loss of what to do now. I finally had to get a backup of the database from the previous hour, download it to my computer, delete the existing dev database, import the new one, go into the console THAT way, make the changes, export this new database, log into the server, pull up psql to manually disconnect anyone connected to the database and then drop it, recreate it and import the one I edited in development.

I will NOT go through that again. There has to be a way to get the rails commands to work and I do not understand how none of the above fixes that worked for others are not working for me.

Comment: What command are you running? `bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: rails c | RAILS_ENV=production rails c | rails c RAILS_ENV=production | it's the same message each time. When I throw bundle exec in there, I get "Please add test-unit gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'` (cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase) (LoadError)" WTF

Comment: That error is promising; is there a stack trace associated with it? Make sure you've run `rvm use 2.2.0` (the same version your server is running on, per the guide).

Comment: So I added that gem to the gemfile and now it's working in production. Unbelievable. I still have to run the bundle exec command, but wow. This has never been an issue until I created this new droplet for the site (it was on a shared droplet with 4 other sites before this). I've used the console numerous times to make quick updates impossible through the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added

```
gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'
```

to Gemfile and all's right with the world again.